# show and hide wifi or GPRS icon in status bar

Tags: android, button, hide, statusbar

i want creat an application in android studio that exemple when i click a button1 the wifi icon in status bar will be hide and another button1-1 show the wifi icon
and the same for GPRS icon if it possible for the others icons??

Answer (score 0):

You don't get to control that. The system shows or hides those icons based on the status of network.